# You are currently using tooling API version 2.2.1. You should upgrade your tooling API client to version 3.0 or later

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, setup-project

I have created gradle project from [here](https://start.spring.io/) and while importing Gradle(STS) from eclipse I am getting error [image] and image of error log is [image]

So, I am not able to import my project. any suggestion?

Comment: any updates, how did you resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Hope this help others]

I know its quite a late response. But, It might help others.

- Download Gradle Zip from Gradle website
- Open your eclipse Preferences
- Select Gradle STS -> choose your gradle directory

This solved mine.

Answer (score -1):

Apologies for unable to reproduce this issue in my Eclipse or STS IDE. But, I have faced this issue in my IntelliJ IDE. The updated version of the IDE resolved this issue.

https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/#section=windows

Comment: It is a comment, not answer. Please write something more, otherwise, it will be closed soon.